# Angular CLI - Cannot ng update @angular/core due to rxjs dependency

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to update angular and angular material to version 6, and I've already updated the cli to allow the new *ng update* command, but when trying to use it to update *@angular/core*, I get an error every time saying that *@angular/flex-layout* has an incompatible peer dependency to rxjs, requiring at least version 5.5.0.

This doesn't make sense, because I have already updated rxjs globally and locally to version 6.2.0, and this is proven when I check the package version.

Console output below:

> ```
> PS F:\Nick\Angular\firebase-work> npm update @angular/core
>     Package "@angular/flex-layout" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.5.0, would install "6.2.0").
> Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.
> PS F:\Nick\Angular\firebase-work> npm view rxjs version
> 6.2.0
> PS F:\Nick\Angular\firebase-work> npm view rxjs -g version
> 6.2.0
> F:\Nick\Angular\firebase-work>
> ```

Comment: Maybe you can try the compatibility-pack with `npm i rxjs-compat`, which adds rxjs 5 legacy support to rxjs 6, to solve the issue until the flex-layout package is updated to support rxjs 6.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/commit/086d038c713f2aff72dbf8a316a26a23b1ee138f), you need to install the release 6.x of Flex Layout:

```
npm i --save @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.15
```